# Is there a way to see console.log without choosing debug js remotely?

Tags: react-native

With old Android versions, app is so slow working when debug js remotely is active. Is there a way to see the logs which we have on Chrome ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Chrome is the issue, you can use [React Native Tools Extension on Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.vscode-react-native). That way you can simply use VS code itself for reading logs.

**EDIT:** If putting Remote Debugger ON the issue, go ahead and use `react-native log-android` or `react-native log-ios` . [Click here for more information on accessing console logs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging#accessing-console-logs)

Comment: This extension needs "Debug Js Remotely" enabled. Is there a way to see logs without choosing debug js remotely?

Comment: Well, then the only way to see logs would be the metro bundler. But that's not readable, for example, if you are logging object values. If it's not visible there, you're probably using an older version of RN. In older versions, I think they had something called `react-native log-android` or something.

Comment: `react-native log-android`   is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the server terminal for that, all consoles are going to be availabe there for you and you wont need to enable "debug remotly"

Comment: How can i use server terminal ? Can you give me an example ?